# Git ignore a directory hierarchy

Tags: c#, git, github, version-control

The asp.net core web app has a folder wwwroot/lib which I want to exclude. But I still want keep wwwroot/js or wwwroot/css etc.

None of the following in .gitignore work:

```
wwwroot/lib/ 
wwwroot/lib
**wwwroot/lib/*
```

The only thing works is lib/ which is too broad. I also modified .gitignore first before I created a new project, so caching should not be an issue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the path for `lib`, `js` and `css` are different, so you can directly add full relate path for `wwwroot/lib` in `.gitignore`:

```
/full/relative/path/for/wwwroot/lib
```

Such as `dotnetCore/dotnetCore/wwwroot/lib`.

If you have added files in `wwwroot/lib` in version control, you can remove them by:

```
git rm /full/relative/path/for/wwwroot/lib/* --cached
```

Such as `git rm dotnetCore/dotnetCore/wwwroot/lib/* --cached`.

Now files in `wwwroot/lib` are totally ignored by git.

**Note:** If you have many projects in git repo, you can use `**` to replace the full relatibe path. Such as `**/wwwroot/lib` in `.gitignore`.

Comment: This actually worked. I now have Mytests/WebApplication1/wwwroot/lib/

Comment: It is not perfect, but given that I probably won't have too many web app in a single solution, this is a good option.

Comment: If you have many projects in git repo, you can use `**/wwwroot/lib` instead. I update it in my answer :)